# How to access Formik values outside the formik component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am just testing out these React codes where Formik is being used. I am trying to get the values out from the Formik component so that it can be used later, Inside the Formik **values** prop is helpful but what about outside the Formik component?

I went through some of the old questions related to the same error, where it was suggested to use `ref` and to use a simple variable and assign it with the values prop inside Formik. So I did the same by assigning the values prop to a local variable, but I ended up with this error:

**Error**

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {correctAnswers}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
> use an array instead.

Here I am assigning the values prop to the local variable

```
{values.correctAnswers.map((answer, index) => {
    return (
        <div className="test-field" key={index}>
        {(checkData = values)} //here assigning the values prop
        <Field
            className="test-field-input"
            type="text"
            name={`correctAnswers.${index}.correctAnswer`}
        />
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

So what can be the solution to overcome this error?

Comment: Why not implement [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)? Also not advised to post code as an image so please make an [edit] with the actual code.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ, could you please tell how to use Context in this code to get the values.

Comment: Do you need to get these values in realtime -- as the user types, or do you need to get them only when the form is submitted?

Comment: @adsy, I need it when the user types the values.